# Unable to make an update java UcanAccess

Tags: java, ms-access, ucanaccess

I'm trying to do an update on a table to a specific row by filtering by id and no long as i try running the query from Java is not saved in the database document.

If I run the query, there's no exceptions and it runs as if it had run successfully, if I do a SELECT to collect the information from Java and see if it has been updated I find that it has been updated correctly, but then if I open the database with MS Access it has not been changed and if I rerun the Java program the changes are not made.

Database class

```
public class NHRPGDatabase {

static Connection connection;

public Connection openConnection() throws SQLException {

    String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://NHRPGBD.accdb";

    return DriverManager.getConnection(url);
}

public void closeConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    connection.close();
}}
```

Query code

```
public boolean updateName(int id, String name) throws SQLException {

    Connection con = db.openConnection();
    con.setAutoCommit(true);
    PreparedStatement update = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE Mi_Cuenta SET HabboNombre=? WHERE Id=?");
    update.setString(1, name);
    update.setInt(2, id);

    int result = update.executeUpdate();

    db.closeConnection(con);

    if (result == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Edit: Still don't know why is not working, if i make a update in a fresh made MS Access database it actually works.
Seems like the database i'm trying to make the update on its db file version is V2010 [VERSION_14] and the one i've created is 2007 VER 12, i don't know if that helps in any way.**

Comment: If data returns in SELECT then it must be in a table somewhere. Are there 2 files?

Comment: @June7 No, I've checked, and the changes that are supposed to be happening aren't saved on the MS Access database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i'm going to answer myself, i discover why is not working, in my MS Access table (where i'm trying to make the update), i have a image row (Ole object) where i have images (bitmap images), i deleted the bitmap images and now it works.